# Docusign Clickwrap "Save_UserAgreement_Error" error on accept

Tags: docusignapi

One of the three Docusign Clickwraps we use has begun returning a 400 error whenever a user tries to accept it. This Clickwrap has previously been working as expected - we last received a successful acceptance on 13th Jan.

This is what is shown in the UI:

[image]

And this is the 400 response:

```
{
  "errorCode": "Save_UserAgreement_Error",
  "message": "Unable to save UserAgreement for clickwrapId: <click wrap id>"
}
```

We see this error when we use the test UI in the Docusign console, so the issue is not in our application's integration with Docusign. The other two Clickwraps we are using are continuing to work as expected. I can't find any documentation on the issue, and I can't see any reported downtime with Docusign.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I can't repo, can you try a different browser, clearing cache etc. Does this happen to more than one user?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding the application url to the list of whitelisted domains in the Clickwrap's configuration. This doesn't explain why this issue occurred suddenly - Clickwraps were being accepted successfully from our application until 13th Jan.